# independent random variables made from chi-square distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory

if $x_1$,...,$x_n$ are r.s from N(0,1), how can we prove $\frac{x_i^2}{\sum_ {j=1}^{n}x_j^2}$ and $\sum_ {j=1}^{n} x_j^2$ are independent?

Comment: Try the Cochran lemma.